# How to separate integers from string in a data frame cell that are separated by commas?

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have a file that has a variety of responses to some questions. Each cell will have anywhere from 1 to 4 numbers, followed by the word "finished" inside of one cell. For example, df[1,1] could equal "-5","2","1","Finished" . I need to be able to get rid of the word finished, and just have the integers so that I can add them together to get one number for that cell. How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read about providing a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Another option using R base apply function:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c('-5,-2,1,Finished','1,2,7,Finished','-3,-2,4,Finished'))

new_df <- apply(df, c(1, 2), FUN = function(x){
  values <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, split = ","))) # Convert cell values to a vector
  values <- values[which(!tolower(values) == "finished")] # Remove Finished
  return(sum(as.numeric(values), na.rm = T)) # Add remaining integer values
})

new_df
  X
[1,] -6
[2,] 10
[3,] -1
```

The above will iterate through every cell in a dataframe. For each cell it convert the cell's values to a vector by splitting on commas. Then it will remove the 'finished' value from the vector and finally sum all remaining numeric values. new_df will be a matrix the same size as df.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, however, it does not seem to be summing my integers. All of my cells are 0's.

Comment: Apologies, updated my answer to make it work, original code was not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One option after reading the file with `read.csv/read.table` is to use `separate_rows` to expand the rows after removing the 'Finished', while using `convert = TRUE` and then get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number(), col2 = str_remove(col2, ",\\s*[Ff]inished")) %>%
     separate_rows(col2, sep= ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
     group_by(rn) %>%
     summarise(col3 = sum(col2, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     select(-rn) %>%
     bind_cols(df1, .)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   col1 col2              col3
#  <int> <chr>            <int>
#1     1 -5,-2,1,Finished    -6
#2     2 -3,-2,5,Finished     0
#3     3 3,4,2,Finished       9
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1$col3 <- sapply(sub(",[Ff]inished", "", df1$col2), function(str1)
            sum(scan(text = str1, what = numeric(), sep=",", quiet = TRUE)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:3, col2 = c('-5,-2,1,Finished', 
    '-3,-2,5,Finished', '3,4,2,Finished'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: When i run this i get the error, "row number() should only be calledin a data context.-5, 2, -5, 1, Finished - This is what the cells look like.

Comment: @DubaMinus I couldn't reproduce it.  Can you test with the data in my post

Comment: @DubaMinus can youo show your `packageVersion('dplyr')` and `packageVersion('tidyr')`

Comment: ‘0.8.3’ for dplyr,  ‘1.0.2’ for tidyr

Comment: I used the devel version of dplyr and 1.0.0 for tidyr

Comment: @DubaMinus just wanted to check whether you get error here `df1 %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number(), col2 = str_remove(col2, ",\\s*[Ff]inished"))` or in the next line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
df <- within(df,
             Y <- sapply(regmatches(X,gregexpr("[+-]?\\d+",X)),
                            function(v) sum(as.integer(v))))
```

such that

```
> df
                 X  Y
1 -5,-2,1,Finished -6
2   1,2,7,Finished 10
3 -3,-2,4,Finished -1
```

**Dummy Data**

```
df <- data.frame(X = c('-5,-2,1,Finished','1,2,7,Finished','-3,-2,4,Finished'))
```